# REST POST Authorization Not Working But Works in PostMan

Tags: vb.net, rest

I'm trying to get authorization via REST POST in VB.Net .4.6 but I can't get it to work. The line Responsecode.EnsureSuccessStatusCode works (return Code 200) but the next line doesn't. It returns `<Response><Status>FAIL</Status><Code>NOT_AUTH</Code><Reason>User not authorized 13</Reason></Response>`

I have tried the POST using Postman and I get a successful authentication but it won't work in code. What am I doing wrong?
[image]

```
    Sub Main()
    Test()
    Console.WriteLine("finished")
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
Public Async Function Test() As Task
    Try
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
        Dim client = New HttpClient()
        Dim request = New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://example.com/common/api/authorize")
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic abcdefREMOVED==")
        request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/xml")

        Dim content = New StringContent("<Request>&vbcrLF<User>abc</User>&vbcrLF<Password>abcREMOVED</Password>&vbcrLF<Type>CUST</Type>&vbcrLF</Request>", Nothing, "application/xml")
        request.Content = content
        Dim response As New HttpResponseMessage
        response = Await client.SendAsync(request)
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
        Console.WriteLine(Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Remove those `&vbcrLF`

Comment: 4.6 is end of life, and no longer receives even basic security patches. It's a bad idea to keep using it. You should update to at least the 4.8 series, which should not require any code changes... just install the updated version of .Net and update the build target, and =poof=, suddenly your code is no longer a walking security incident in waiting.

Answer (score 0):

The return code 200 means that the request got to the endpoint and the endpoint sent back a response.  You'll need to follow up with whoever is responsible for the API you're using and ask them what "user not authorized 13" means.